# position toast relative to other view

Tags: android, position, toast

I need to implement a custom Toast which position changes according to other views on the screen.
Basically what I'm looking for is a layout_alignBelow option for the toast...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to calculate the expected *x-axis* and *y-axis* of your `Toast` relative to your `Views` on the screen. Afterwards, create a custom Toast and pass the axis information to it:

```
int x, y;  //needs to be calculated

Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your message",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG);  
t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y);
t.show();
```

For more, info read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Positioning).